# Best filter to use for cold brew?

Tags: cold-brew

What's the best filter material to use for DIY set up for cold brew coffee?

When I used a pour over funnel with a standard paper filter it seems to get clogged up faster than when hot brewing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the very same problem with cold brew taking a long time. Though we have a few Q/A about this in the [cold-brew](/questions/tagged/cold-brew) already, I think could stand on its own!

**I use a "two-phase" method**: using **first a "primary" or "coarse" filter**, like a French press plunger as described [here](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/a/423/262) and elsewhere, or a metal mesh tea or coffee filter as described [here](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/a/432/262), or even a sock or cloth as suggested [by this question](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/2017/262). This strains through quickly, but only filters the larger particles that would very quickly clog a paper filter. **Second, I put it through a paper filter** (I find Hario-style filters drain faster than Melitta-style filters). I find this works the best of any setup I have used.

For completeness, we have a few Q/A about this already. See for example [making cold-brew easier](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/431/262) for some more ideas about "pre-filtering"; see [starting out and equipment](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/400/262) for some other tips; and even try [cold brewing with AeroPress](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/2073/262).

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten good results cold brewing with an aeropress filter, as well as using a V60 bamboo paper filter. 
Make sure that you add 2 filters, one below your ground coffee and one on top, so that the drops are evenly distributed into the coffee.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the easiest and cleanest way to make cold brew coffee is with a pitcher and a milk bag.  I also use filtered water to make sure I get the best tasting cold brew I can since we drink so much of it.  ChestBrew has a great [how-to video](http://www.chestbrew.com/how-to) on this method that's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

These work well for me

[https://www.amazon.com/Cold-Brew-Coffee-Filters/dp/B072MGP456](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B072MGP456)

I don't like to have a bunch of equipment, so these get the job done for me.